# Flask request getting truncated?

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I'm trying to create a small app with oauth2 user verification.
Receiving a request (GET) with a token, I try to validate the token and I'm getting weird errors.
Now I've traced this down to the GET request being segmented (TCP) and the app receiving part of the token. Just missing a couple of bytes, so the signature is invalid but the data is there.
Granted, the token is long (927 bytes) my MTU is kinda small (1300, cisco VPN client)

```
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/metrics') 
def get_metrics():

  # Get access token from request
  bearer = request.headers.get('Authorization') 
  if not bearer:
    raise Exception('Mere mortals should not care this mantra')
  # Strip Bearer and \n
  tl = len(bearer)
  token = bearer[7:]
  print('>', tl, token)
```

Wireshark shows request is being segmented, the token lies just across, and request.headers.get() returns just the first part.
Am I missing something ? Interestingly(?), if I add 'Content-length: 1200' to postman, it works...

Ideas ? Bug ?
TIA,
-Carlos

I was expecting requests to deal with TCP reassembly...